# Problem with exporting text

Tags: export, string-manipulation

I prepared in Mathematica some long text:

```
text = string1 <> string2 <> ... <> stringn;
```

(some strings contains TeX code). Then I would like to export text to some text file and I use:

```
Export[path,text,"Text"]
```

Unfortunatelly, when I look into the file instead of the expected text I found Mathematica command:

```
StringJoin[string1,string2,...]
```

What to do, to have text, which I created in Mathematica in my file?

Answer (score 1):

use `ToString` and `" "` enclose the text. And insert blank   `"\ "` or `"\n"` when we need some format.

```
text = ToString[α + a // HoldForm // TeXForm] <> "\ " <> 
   "a,b,c" <> "\ " <> "A+B+C";
Export["new.txt", text, "Text"]
Import["new.txt"]
```

```
text = ToString[α + a //HoldForm//TeXForm] <> "\n" <> "a,b,c" <> "\n" <>
    "A+B+C";
Export["new.txt", text, "Text"]
Import["new.txt"]
```